# android webview current location is not working for kitkat version

Tags: android, webview, location, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using webview in my application. In that i am not able to get the current location.

I gave permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

in onCreate method of my activity class i have

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
```

and in my PQChromeClient() method

```
 @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);

        //TODO: temporary commented
        requestPermission();
        turnGPSOn();
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }


   private void requestPermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MySocialNetworkActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

        Toast.makeText(MySocialNetworkActivity.this,"GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MySocialNetworkActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){
        //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

This code is working for lollipop and marshmallow but not for kitkat.
Recently i updated my Android studio from 2.15 to 2.2. Is this update creating any problem?

Answer (score 1):

It should be supported, as KitKat is already using a Chromium-based WebView. Anyway, this can give you a clue: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview You should check WebView package version in Play Store in the device to see if it's updated, as maybe you're using an old version in this particular device.